# input[type="text"]:disabled not working for IE

Tags: css

I want to change control's background color, when it is on disabled. For that I am using:

In css file

```
 input[type="text"]:disabled{background:red;}
```

in Html file

`<input tyepe="text" disabled="" >`

it is working properly on Chrome and Mozilla, but not working in Internet Explorer.

How can I fix that.

Thanks.

Comment: http://selectivizr.com/

Comment: What version of IE are you referring to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only IE9+ supports the `:disabled` pseudo-selector as per the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj127307%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) docs. IE7+ supports CSS attributes selectors though:

```
input[type="text"][disabled] {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: I would do `input[type="text"][disabled]` since disabled is a boolean attribute and doesn't need to have a value.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me in IE9

```
input[type="text"][disabled="disabled"]{background:red;}
```

Comment: This is the same what Blade0rz said 4 min ago. only difference is that he print [disabled=disabled] and you print [disabled="disabled
"]

Comment: @MichaelVayvala, my answer came like 10 seconds after his since we wrote it at the same time.